# Making monitor selection persistent

Tags: display

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Gnome 3.18.5 on a laptop. I usually have the laptop attached to an external monitor. Each time I boot up with the external monitor attached, I go into System Settings, Screen Display to turn off the laptop's screen, leaving just the external monitor on. I know that I can also use xrandr to toggle between the two displays. I was hoping to be able to achieve a situation in which the laptop's screen would automatically be off when I booted up with the external monitor attached. I found a script that was said to achieve that outcome, to be put into etc/X11/xsession.d, but it had no effect for me. Then I thought I'd try to create custom keyboard shortcuts to toggle between the two displays, but they didn't work either.

Can anyone suggest anything else I should try?

Thanks,

Leslie